# What to put as s3_conn_id if SFTPToS3Operator already with AWS permissions?

Tags: python, airflow

I want to use SFTPToS3Operator, however airflow is already in AWS and has all the IAM permissions necessary to write to S3. What should I pass to `s3_conn_id` when in this case I don't have and airflow doesn't need?

Comment: I recon you can put just any valid `conn_id` name, i.e. a `Connection` by that name should exist in your `Airflow` deployment (webserver > Admin > Connections). By default, it is assigned the value [`aws_default`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/63751c3e53d0240617dd29b2e0833b50a8a261d7/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/sftp_to_s3.py#L58)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source, the operator makes use of the `S3Hook` which inherits from `AwsBaseHook`. This one checks for usable aws creds, which if they are not, then will fall back to using environment variable creds. So the answer is leave`s3_conn_id` blank.

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/base_aws.py